# TypeError: enterEmail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'email'

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I am working on building out a page object model Selenium framework in Python, but I am currently getting this error "TypeError: enterEmail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'email'"

I have this as my action in a Selenium test:

```
LoginPage.enterLoginEmail(driver, email)
```

And this is the class:

```
class LoginPage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    #Locators
    email_address = 'email'
    pw = 'password'


    def enterLoginEmail(self, driver, email):
        self.login_email = driver.find_element_by_id(email_address)
        self.login_email.send_keys(email)
```

Comment: this is bad practice. you are creating a new instance variable outside of the `__init__`

Comment: I have a variable set up for email as well within the test, as well as driver.

Comment: anyways, the problem I guess is you need to initialize a new `LoginPage` object, since you're not calling a class method. So like `LoginPage(driver).enterLoginEmail(driver, email)`

Comment: Actually, he's NOT creating a new instance.  He's calling it as if it were a class method.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think you might have misread one of my comment

Comment: I don't disagree at all

Comment: to clarify when I said "you're not calling a class method", I meant that it's being treated *like* a class method, but it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because you do not have an object, so "driver" is assigned to "self", and "email" is assigned to "driver".  Perhaps you meant

```
LoginPage(driver).enterLoginEmail(driver,email)
```

to create and use a temporary object.

Comment: a minor thing, but based on the signature it should be `LoginPage(driver)`

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Is there a best practice here where I don't have to keep repeating driver for every action?

Example if I were to do:
```LoginPage(driver).enterLoginPassword(driver,password)```

Comment: just remove the `driver` argument to the method. then call `self.driver` within the method.

Comment: Why are you using a class for this in the first place?  Why not just call a function?

Comment: The Selenium page object model framework calls to define each page to be automated as a class.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class LoginPage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def enterLoginEmail(self, driver, email):
        driver.find_element_by_id(email_address).send_keys("aaa@gmail.com")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).